# So, we don't use "what happens?", do we?

Tags: word-usage

Most of time I heard native English speakers say either "*What is happening?*" or "*what happened?*".

When do we use "*happen*" in present tense?

So, we don't use "*what happens?*", do we?

Comment: Oh yes, we do. And then, what happens?

Comment: @Kris: I think you have just fallen into OPs trap. That may be hypothetical or it may be future, but it is not a simple present.

Comment: @TimLymington It is a simple present-tense form; it just happens (!) to carry a semantic nuance beyond simple presentness. Or rather, it carries the nuance of _general_ presentness (like most simple presents in English), unlike the progressive forms which carry the nuance of _current, simultaneous, progressive_ presentness.

Comment: "You should see what happens when you put Mentos in Diet Coke."  "Why, [what happens](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1gS3eMn4Cic)?"

Comment: What happens if I push this big red button here?

Comment: @Wayfaring, in this case "happen" carrying  the future meaning right? What will happen if I push this red button here?

Comment: @user105551 Yes, future. "What will happen if..." is quite a bit more formal sounding.

Answer (score 0):

"what's happening?" Is in the present continuous tense, which is used to talk about things happening at the moment. This is a fairly common question to inquiring about things happening now.

You can use 'happen' in present simple when you talk about things in general that don't apply to a specific time:

what kind of things happen at oktoberfest? (In general, every year)
What's happening at oktoberfest? (Whats happening this year?)

It's also popular in some sayings:
what happens in Vegas, stays in Vegas (again, this is disconnected from a particular 'now' time)